# How to scrape a specific word from a div of pages on wikidata?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the word 'human' from the info of persons I search on wikidata.org.

For example, for the page https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q5284, the word human exists in the following div:

```
<div class="wikibase-snakview-value wikibase-snakview-variation-valuesnak"><a title="Q5" href="/wiki/Q5">human</a></div>
```

I am using the following code, which produces the whole line above, not only the word 'human' :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q1124')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser')
x = soup.find("div", attrs={"class":"wikibase-snakview-value wikibase-snakview-variation-valuesnak",  "data-value": False},)
```

And if I use the method `.get('href')` on `x` I get `None`.
What should I do to get the word 'human' only as the outcome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should try like this:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q1124')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

x = soup.find("div", attrs={"class":"wikibase-snakview-value wikibase-snakview-variation-valuesnak"})

# to get the word 'human'
print(x.text)
# to get the 'href'
print(x.find('a').get('href'))
```

output:

```py
human
/wiki/Q5
```

Comment: thanks you all for the reply. another question, is there a way to scrap the text by defining the class and title as there are many div with the same class name but with different titles?

Comment: yes you can do that

Comment: for example, `print(soup.find('h2', attrs={"dir": "auto", "id": "claims"}).text)` this will give you the text `Statements`.  here we parsed an element using two attributes `dir` and `id`, similarly, you can use many attributes(like `class` and `title`) to locate an element

Comment: thanks. but for my example, if the title is '/wiki/Q5', how to use it with the class to get the word 'human'.

Comment: there is no need to use `class` attribute with the `title` attribute to locate the element and you also can not because `class` and `title` are the attribute of two different tags. you can get the text just by the attribute `title`. like this `print(soup.find('a', {"title": "Q5"}).text)` . this will print the text `human`

Answer (score 2):

Main issue because you get `None` for the `href` is that you select the `div` and not the `a`. `div` do not have a `href` attribute

Following would work:

```
x.a.get('href')
```

To get the text from the `a` simply use `text` or `get_text()`:

```
x.a.get_text()
```

Or use [`css selector`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to be more specific and more comfortable in notation:

```
soup.select_one('.wikibase-snakview-value.wikibase-snakview-variation-valuesnak a').text
```

Answer (score 2):

After running that code, the `x` variable holds this entire div:

```
<div class="wikibase-snakview-value wikibase-snakview-variation-valuesnak"><a href="/wiki/Q5" title="Q5">human</a></div>
```

That div itself doesn't have an `href` attribute, the enclosed anchor does. You need to find the anchor, then you could get the `href` from it, but what you're really after is the text inside the tag.

```
anchor = x.find('a')
href = anchor.get('href')
print(href)
print(anchor.text)
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the element present in the field "Instance of" in the Wikidata, try with the below code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q23907')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
word = soup.find("div", attrs={"class": "wikibase-snakview-value wikibase-snakview-variation-valuesnak"}).a.text
print(word)
```

Here I tested with another page, feel free to test with any page you want to get the element field value from.

Answer (score 1):

You could find the `div` with the correct class, then find the `a` tag inside this `div`, and finally get the text inside the `a` tag.

Try this:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q5284')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
div = soup.find("div", attrs={"class": "wikibase-snakview-value wikibase-snakview-variation-valuesnak"})
if div:
    a = div.find('a')
    if a:
        print(a.text)
```